# TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable when using model.fit()

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I tried to fit my model, but encountered 'type error'. This code was written almost the same as described in a kaggle source code example for CNN.

https://www.kaggle.com/kanncaa1/convolutional-neural-network-cnn-tutorial/notebook

However, continuously the type error occurs. I changed `model.fit_generator` to `model. fit` because the function is updated from the new version of tensorflow. I guessed `shape[0]` could make this int-relevant issue. Could anyone help to point out the wrong type in the code below?

```
# model fitting
# from tensorflow 2.1.0
history = model.fit(datagen.flow(train_x, train_y, batch_size = batch_size),
                          epochs = epochs,
                          validation_data = (valid_x, valid_y),
                          steps_per_epoch = train_x.shape[0] // batch_size)
```

Comment: You better check the train_x, it seems like train_x.shape returns an integer. You might have a problem with loading data because your input shape has a single dim.

Answer (score 0):

Possible Solutions:

run `print(x_train.shape)` , and make sure all the values except the first dimension match the `input_shape` that you specified during the model definition. If you ported the code from the kaggle kernel then I assume your model was defined as:

```
model.add(Conv2D(filters = 8, kernel_size = (5,5),padding = 'Same', 
                 activation ='relu', input_shape = (28,28,1)))
```

Make Sure that `x_train.shape` is in accordance with the specified `input_shape`.

Comment: I really appreciate to your answer. 
However, the input shape was correct and double checked according to your answer. 
The result of running code `print(train_x.shape)` is `(15000, 249, 1, 1)`.
So, I already changed `input_shape = (249, 1, 1)`.